# Is it possible to programatically change the workspace address of a sharepoint project using CSOM in C#

Tags: sharepoint, project, csom

I am currently using [Project.UpdateProjectWorkspaceAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-class/gg178089(v=office.15)) method of the Project Class. I want to be able to do the same using CSOM.

I have tried to find a possible method as the UpdateProjectWorkspaceAddress for CSOM. I was unable to find any.